# Set alternate content until a specific date with Apache RewriteRule and RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, osx-server

I need to serve an under construction page until a specific date, but I will be out of the country on the day the new content needs to display, and for a week and a half after (I know, first world problems...)

What I currently have serving the under_construction page in my httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \
http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/under_construction/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

What I would like to use is below, but I don't fully understand how it should work, and of course it isn't working properly because it isn't configured properly. I have tried changing out the time string to get it to change a few minutes after the restart, but the configuration is probably not right to begin with.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \
RewriteCond ^{TIME} < 201304220000
http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/under_construction/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \
RewriteCond ^{TIME} > 201304220000
http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/content/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

Am I at least on the right track? Also, besides localhost:80/server-status, is there any way to see the status of Apache (date, time, etc.), from Terminal for instance? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget the day itself, use either `<=` or `>=`. Otherwise, you will  be offline for a day.

Comment: I still get the error I mentioned below. Anytime I add a RewriteCond to the rule, the browser can't connect to the server. This happens whether there is the second rule or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed between the comparison operator and the [`CondPattern`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20130422000000
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \
http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/under_construction/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20130422000000
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \
http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/content/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

Also don't forget to use `>=` or `<=`, depending on whether you want to switch on that day or a day later.

Comment: After a few tests, this is now working. Thank you so much! Related, however, I tried out some specific times to test that it was changing properly, and the >= caused errors. If I simply make the under_construction time <20130422000000, and the content time >20130422000000, it seems to change on that time without skipping. I tried with <20130417124000 and >20130417124000, and at 12:40, upon refresh the content switched perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need the `RewriteCond` *before* the rule that it is applied to:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} < 20130422000000
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/under_construction/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{TIME} > 20130422000000
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/content/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

The `%{TIME}` variable is the 4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit date, 2 digit hour, 2 digit minute, and 2 digit second.

Comment: For some reason, whenever I add RewriteCond %{TIME} > 20130422000000 to the https-vhosts.conf file, I get an error that "Safari Can't Connect to Server". If I remove the RewriteCond, it goes back to normal. I have tried changing the date/time, still nothing.

Comment: sorry, httpd-vhosts.conf