# Time lock for mod_rewrite in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have question:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (safari|navigator) [NC]
RewriteCond IF SOMEONE ASK, IN LESS THAN 30 SECONDS (HALF MINUTE) FOR FILES IN FOLDERS  (folder1|folder2|folder3) 
RewriteRule ^((?!folder3/).*)$ /folder3/$1 [L,NC]
```

Perhaps more simplified:

```
RewriteCond IF SOMEONE ASK, IN LESS THAN 30 SECONDS (HALF MINUTE) FOR FILES IN FOLDERS  (folder1|folder2|folder3) 
RewriteRule ^((?!folder3/).*)$ /folder3/$1 [L,NC]
```

If someone ask (some browser) apache http server for files in folder1 and folder2 in less than 30 seconds but than ask for files in folder3 after that period of time ex. (in 45 seconds or 2 minutes) than rewriterule won't be executed. 
Files from all three folders must be reqested in less than 30 seconds in order to rewriterule work it's job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is unfortunately: **"no, you can't do it in .htaccess"**

There is no available variable in `mod_rewrite` that lets you access the file modification/creation time and write conditions agains it.

[See full list of mod_rewrite variable](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#Mod_Rewrite_Variables)

**Only option** is to forward the request to a PHP controller and do this check inside PHP code.

Comment: Is it complicated to do it using php? Can you give me some help? If it is too compicated than nothing...

Comment: I have found link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057024/set-alternate-content-until-a-specific-date-with-apache-rewriterule-and-rewritec        RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20130422000000 Is it useful?

Comment: `%{TIME}` is actually server time not file modification time.

Comment: I guess it is... too bad This was an excellent time lock for some files... Regards...

Comment: Anubhava I put you here another link for modified question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017466/sequence-line-of-some-files-from-differnt-folders-in-order-to-rewrite-in-do-it-j