# What to change in .htaccess so it stop showing subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.myurlname\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "safa" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://m.myurlname.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now, It works but not as I want. My wish is that visitor don't see that content is rewrite from subdomain. I want it to always showing myurlname.com and not m.myurlname.com as it does now.

Comment: Try the link [Link](http://davidwalsh.name/block-domain) Hope its useful.

Comment: You can't hide subdomain unless you enable `mod_proxy` in Apache config.

Comment: Thank you very much. Regards.